# Android text and design

Tags: android, android-theme

All the videos I watch have a text and design tab, but mine doesn't.

I found this on the internet:
`Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

but it didn't work on mine
how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I'd recommend you spend some more time studying Android,  sounds like you don't have the basics down yet.

Answer (score 0):

[image: check out this image]

you can switch tab mode using those buttons

Answer (score 0):

"split" view is a relatively new feature to Android Studio. You can read a little about it
[here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-studio-design-tools-ux-changes-split-view-dcde75e88a0c).

You may be using an older version of Android Studio. Be sure that you install the latest version for this feature to be enabled.

`Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` is related to your app's styling, not the IDE. It isn't really relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmP0Y.png)its 3.6.2 i just download it today

Comment: is this really a mistake or are there no tabs anymore and the videos I watched are old? I'm really trying to just start myself, sorry